# Check whether a generic DbSet has an Identity Key

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

**Question**: having a generic `DbSet<T>`, how can I know if the class T has an identity key?

This is my case:

```cs
public static string SqlCodeGenerator<T>(DbContext context) where T : class
{
    var query = string.Emtpy;
    var set = context.Set<T>();

    if (set.HasIdentity())
        query += "SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON;\n";

    // Continue building query...
}
```

I don't need to know which property, only if it has or has not (although gives extra points to the answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More flexible approach, not directly linked to SQL Server, but it covers Identity columns. At least those properties which are marked with `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` attribute

```
foreach (var key in dbContext.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(Entity)).GetKeys())
{
    foreach (var property in key.Properties)
    {
        if (property.ValueGenerated == Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.ValueGenerated.OnAdd)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("gotcha!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Combined both answers to do this: `var hasIdentity = efProperties.Any(p => p.ValueGenerated != ValueGenerated.Never);`!!

Comment: @EmilianoRuiz Actually that's not enough if you are writing generic code - there could be other client or server value generators attached, HiLo strategy etc. The term "IdentityColumn" is specific for the database provider. The other answer looks more correct, especially if you are using SqlServer specific syntax in your generator.

Answer (score 3):

Solved both with some creativity and Linq:

```cs
var efEntity = context.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(T));
var efProperties = efEntity.GetProperties();

var hasIdentity = efProperties.Any(p => (SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy)
    p.FindAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy").Value
    == SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);

var identityProperty = efProperties.FirstOrDefault(p => (SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy)
    p.FindAnnotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy").Value
    == SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn);
```

With libraries:

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata;
using System.Linq;
```